# Java - Constructor woes and System.out.print from within methods

Tags: java

Hey there,
I'm stuck.  I've got this hw assignment with 2 problems in the code that I'm at a loss on how to fix.  The assignment is mostly nonsense:

```
import java.util.*;

class Business {
    private String name, phone;
    private int employees, age;

    void Business(){
        name = "Foo Inc.";
        phone = "";
        employees = 0;
        age = 0;

        System.out.println("In default constructor!");
        printVals();
    }

    void Business(String name, String phone, int employees){ 
        System.out.printf("%s %s %d\n", name, phone, employees);

        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.employees = employees;
        this.age = 0;

        System.out.println("In constructor!");
        printVals();
    }

    void printVals(){
        System.out.printf("name: %s\n", name);
        System.out.printf("phone: %s\n", phone);
        System.out.printf("employees: %d\n", employees);
        System.out.printf("age: %d\n", age);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Business[] mall = new Business[5];
        String[] names = {"The Gap",
                          "Savers",
                          "Academy of Salon Professionals",
                          "Ron's Farmhouse"};
        String[] phones = {"555-555-5555", "555-555-5556", 
                           "555-555-5557", "555-555-5558"};
        int[] emps = {20, 24, 75, 32};
        int i, num = 4;


        mall[num - 1] = new Business();
        for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
            mall[i] = new Business(names[i], phones[i], emps[i]);
            System.out.printf("init Business: %s %s %d\n", 
                    names[i], phones[i], emps[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the output error from javac:

```
Business.java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Business(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int)
location: class Business
            mall[i] = new Business(names[i], phones[i], emps[i]);
                      ^
1 error
```

I don't see why it's tell me it can't find the constructor.  As far as I can tell, the parameters are the same...

Let's say I comment out the parameters of the Business() calls, such that it's only calling the default constructor.  At least that way it compiles, but then, none of the System.out.print*'s from within the methods will print anything!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining a constructor with `void Business`. Constructors don't have return types so simply remove the void before your Business "constructors" and `new` will be able to find them.

```
/* remove void */ 
Business(String name, String phone, int employees){ 
    System.out.printf("%s %s %d\n", name, phone, employees);

    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.employees = employees;
    this.age = 0;

    System.out.println("In constructor!");
    printVals();
}
```

Comment: Good play for actually describing 'why' void should not be in the Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `void` from the Constructors